# Invoke RFT method from java class

Tags: rft

We are building an excel based IBM RFT framework, for which we want to invoke RFT individual methods(not the test script that can be executed from command line) from an external java file.

Anyone has an insight on this?

Thanks in Advance.

-Sreenisha Sreenivasan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about  making RFT script as the driver script  and reading the excel   and executing the method..

```
public void testMain(Object[] args) 
{

    String method = getNextAction();
    TestObject target  = getNextTarget();   
    //Using RFT's method here, Own Implementation preferred
    FtReflection.invokeMethod(method, target);      
}
//Get the next object to perform action on
TestObject getNextTarget()
{
       //Here do the operation of finding the object that may be from map or obtained using  find() api of rft 
      return untitledNotepadwindow();
}
//Get the next action to be performed, this should actually return an
//object that has a name to invoke , and arguments  to be passed.
String getNextAction()
{
    return "close";
}
```